# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, api

mi problema esque en mi lista aperece en blanco y tengo este error: es el siguiente tengo un **RecyclerView** para trae el **formato Json de la web** el que intento pasarle los parametros del  adaptador ymostrar una lista de productos asignados El tema esta en que no me muestra la lista solo se queda en blanco ,el siguiente error **E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**
al ver el error en el terminal me sale clase protected void Oncreate()
....

---

MainActivity();

```
package proyecto_ventas.activities;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.R;
import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.adapters.ProductosAdapter;
import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.api.Api;
import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.api.RequestHandler;
import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.models.Productos;



public class MainActivity extends   AppCompatActivity  {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        List<Productos> productosList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewProductos);
        productosList = new ArrayList<>();

        readProductos();

    }

            private void readProductos(){
                PerfomNetWordRequest request = new PerfomNetWordRequest(Api.URL_READ_PRODUCTOS,null,Api.CODE_GET_REQUEST);
                request.execute();
            }


            private void  refreshContenidoList(JSONArray contenido) throws  JSONException{
            //limpiamos los productos anteriores
                productosList.clear();


                //recibimos la respuesta del json
                for(int i=0; i < contenido.length(); i++){
                    //obtenemos los json de nuestros productos
                    JSONObject obj = contenido.getJSONObject(i);
                    productosList.add(new Productos(
                            obj.getLong("id"),
                            obj.getString("titulo"),
                            obj.getString("descripcion"),
                            obj.getString("contenido"),
                            obj.getString("imagen"),
                            new BigDecimal(obj.getString("precio")),
                            obj.getDouble("calificacion"),
                            obj.getInt("categoria")

                    ));
                }
                // creamos el adaptador para configurar en la vista del front json
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                mAdapter = new ProductosAdapter(productosList, R.layout.card_view_productos, new ProductosAdapter.OnclickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(Productos productos, int position) {

                    }
                }, new ProductosAdapter.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(Productos productos, int position) {

                    }
                });

                mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            }


        private class PerfomNetWordRequest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            String url;
            HashMap<String, String> params;

            int requestCode;

            PerfomNetWordRequest(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int requestCode) {
                this.url = url;
                this.params=params;
                this.requestCode = requestCode;
            }
            //la operacion de red realizara en segundo plano
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground (Void...voids){

                RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
                if(requestCode == Api.CODE_POST_REQUEST)
                    return  requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url,params);
                if ((requestCode== Api.CODE_GET_REQUEST))
                    return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
                    if (!object.getBoolean("error")){
                        //refrescamos la lista despues de cada operacion.
                        //para tener una lista actualizada
                        refreshContenidoList(object.getJSONArray("contenido"));
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



        }
    }
```

### Productos adapter

ProductosAdarpter();

```
package idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.R;
import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.api.Api;
import idat.edu.pe.proyecto_ventas.models.Productos;

public class ProductosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Productos>  Lproductos ;
    private int layout;
    private OnclickListener listener;
    private OnLongClickListener listenerLong;

    private Context context;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public ProductosAdapter(List<Productos> productos,int layout,OnclickListener listener,OnLongClickListener listenerLong){
        this.Lproductos = productos;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.listenerLong = listenerLong;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder  vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        context = parent.getContext();
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(Lproductos.get(position),listener,listenerLong);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  Lproductos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView titulo;
        private TextView descripcion;
        private TextView precio;
        private ImageView imagen;

        //CASTEAMOS LAS INSTANCIAS DEL DESIGN
        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            titulo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitulo);
            descripcion = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescripcion);
            precio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewPrecio);
            imagen = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenViewProducto);
        }
        //PASAMOS LOS ATRIBUTOS
        public void bind(final Productos productos,final OnclickListener listener,final OnLongClickListener listenerLong){

            titulo.setText(productos.getTitulo());
            descripcion.setText(productos.getDescripcion());
            //convertimos en string el BigDecimal
            String precioConvercion = String.valueOf(productos.getPrecio());
            //Mostramos imagen con el picasso que venga por la api web
            Picasso.get().load(Api.GALERIA + productos.getImagen()).fit().into(imagen);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  listener.onItemClick(productos,getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                    listenerLong.onItemClick(productos,getAdapterPosition());
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
    }
    //CREAMOS CLASES ANONIMAS
    public interface OnclickListener{
        void onItemClick(Productos productos, int position);
    }

    //CREAMOS CLASES ANONIMAS
    public interface OnLongClickListener{
        void onItemClick(Productos productos, int position);
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento utilizas el Adaptador? Porque veo que lo tienes declarado como variable, que lo usas en el método `refreshContenidoList(etc)` pero no veo que lo estes asignando al `onCreate(etc)` en ningún lado... Fijate que en el `onCreate` solo declaras el mpétodo `readProductos()`...

Comment: Tengo dudas de si onPostExecute sigue estando en background... así que prueba lo siguiente: en el onCreate (UI thread) haz el setAdapter.  Mi consejo es que no pases por constructor los items List<Productos> productos, sólo pasa los listeners y crea un método update(productos: List<Productos>) que haga el notifyDataSetChanged.  Con ésto ya debería funcionar.  Y un detallito, en el propio xml indícale al adapter cuál es el layoutManager, así ya no necesitas setearlo programáticamente.